# cannot see HOSTNAME field in /etc/sysconfig/network file in RedHat Linux

Tags: networking, redhat-enterprise-linux, hostname

I am trying to set up HOSTNAME to a machine , but I am unable to find the HOSTNAME field in the /etc/sysconfig/network file

all I can see is this below

```
# Generated by anaconda
NETWORKING=yes
NTPSERVERARGS=iburst
```

Can anyone let me know how can I change the HOSTNAME in this scenario ?

Comment: Welcome on SuperUser _user614762_. Register yourself, so you can upvote the answer they give you (and choose as the one that you prefer)... Moreover you could really start to like and enjoy this site ;)

Answer (score 3):

There is a utility available in RHEL to permanently set the hostname:

```
sudo hostnamectl set-hostname newhostname
```

Alternatively on RHEL 7 you can simply edit (or create if needed) the file /etc/hostname and add the desired hostname as the only content in the file.

I believe the method you are using is only applicable to RHEL 6 and earlier. If that applies to you, then simply add a hostname field in the format below to that file and reboot:

```
HOSTNAME=newhostname
```